# Proper <img/> source for ASP.net project?

Tags: html, asp.net, image, path

I'm having trouble understanding how to get images to display on this ASP.net project. I'm used to using  tags, but am having trouble with the paths.

I have tried all of these solutions and none cause the image to display:

```
  <img src="~/Images/mask.png" alt="Sample Photo" />
  <img src="~/Images/mask.png" alt="Sample Photo" runat="server" />
  <img src="../Images/mask.png" alt="Sample Photo" />
  <img src="Images/mask.png" alt="Sample Photo" />
  <img src="../Images/mask.png" alt="Sample Photo" />
```

The Images folder is in the project root. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 and no other CSS.

If I set the src to a link (to Imgur, for example), the image displays. This makes me think it's an issue with the path, but I don't know what it could be. I think I've tried every variation that I came across when googling.

Any guidance would be really appreciated, and please let me know if I need to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place images in wwwroot folder.[Details in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0)